# Similar strings, different results

Tags: json, bash, awk

I'm creating a Bash script to parse the air pollution levels from the webpage:
http://aqicn.org/city/beijing/m/

There is a lot of stuff in the file, but this is the relevant bit:

> "iaqi":[{"p":"pm25","v":[**59**,21,112],"i":"Beijing pm25 (fine
>   particulate matter)  measured by U.S Embassy Beijing Air Quality
>   Monitor
>   (\u7f8e\u56fd\u9a7b\u5317\u4eac\u5927\u4f7f\u9986\u7a7a\u6c14\u8d28\u91cf\u76d1\u6d4b).
>   Values are converted from \u00b5g/m3 to AQI levels using the EPA
>   standard."},{"p":"pm10","v":[**15**,5,69],"i":"Beijing pm10
>   (respirable particulate matter)  measured by Beijing Environmental
>   Protection Monitoring Center

I want the script to parse and display 2 numbers: current PM2.5 and PM10 levels (the numbers in **bold** in the above paragraph).

```
CITY="beijing"
AQIDATA=$(wget -q 0 http://aqicn.org/city/$CITY/m/ -O -)

PM25=$(awk -v FS="(\"p\":\"pm25\",\"v\":\\\[|,[0-9]+)" '{print $2}' <<< $AQIDATA)
PM100=$(awk -v FS="(\"p\":\"pm10\",\"v\":\\\[|,[0-9]+)" '{print $2}' <<< $AQIDATA)

echo $PM25 $PM100
```

Even though I can get PM2.5 levels to display correctly, I cannot get PM10 levels to display. I cannot understand why, because the strings are similar.

Anyone here able to explain?

Comment: The data looks suspiciously like JSON. Have you considered using an AWK or Bash JSON parser? There are some listed at http://www.json.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [chw21's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621823/chw21) explains why your approach didn't work.
- [peak's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35545340/45375) is the most robust, because it employs proper JSON parsing.

If you don't want to or can't use third-party utility `jq` for JSON parsing, I suggest using `sed` rather than `awk`, because `awk` is not a good fit for *field*-based parsing of this data.

```
$ sed -E 's/^.*"pm25"[^[]+\[([0-9]+).+"pm10"[^[]+\[([0-9]+).*$/\1 \2/' <<< "$AQIDATA"
59 15
```

The above should work with both GNU and BSD/OSX `sed`.

To read the result into variables:

```
read pm25 pm10 < \
  <(sed -E 's/^.*"pm25"[^[]+\[([0-9]+).+"pm10"[^[]+\[([0-9]+).*$/\1 \2/' <<< "$AQIDATA")
```

<sup>Note how I've chosen lowercase variable names, because it's best to avoid all upper-case variables in shell programming, so as to avoid conflicts with special shell and environment variables.</sup>

If you can't rely on the *order* of the values in the source string, use two separate `sed` commands:

```
pm25=$(sed -E 's/^.*"pm25"[^[]+\[([0-9]+).*$/\1/' <<< "$AQIDATA")
pm10=$(sed -E 's/^.*"pm10"[^[]+\[([0-9]+).*$/\1/' <<< "$AQIDATA")
```

Comment: All very good comments. I accept this as an answer only because it is clear and it does not rely on parsing JSON (which I know nothing about and I am too lazy to learn).

Answer (score 3):

The following approach is based on two steps:

(1) Extracting the relevant JSON;

(2) Extracting the relevant information from the JSON using a JSON-aware tool -- here [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq).

(1) Ideally, the web service would provide a JSON API that would allow one to obtain the JSON directly, but as the URL you have is intended for viewing with a browser, some form of screen-scraping is needed.  There is a certain amount of brittleness to such an approach, so here I'll just provide something that currently works:

```
wget -O - http://aqicn.org/city/beijing/m |
  gawk 'BEGIN{RS="function"}
         $1 ~/getAqiModel/ {
         sub(/.*var model=/,"");
         sub(/;return model;}/,"");
         print}'
```

(gawk or an awk that supports multi-character RS can be used; if you have another awk, then first split on "function", using e.g.:

sed $'s/function/\\\n/g' # three backslashes )

The output of the above can be piped to the following jq command, which performs the filtering envisioned in (2) above.

(2)

```
jq -c '.iaqi | .[]
| select(.p? =="pm25" or .p? =="pm10") | [.p, .v[0]]'
```

The result:

```
["pm25",59]
["pm10",15]
```

Comment: Nicely done - using a JSON parser is the most robust approach; note that your `awk` command, due to using a multi-character `RS` value, requires either GNU Awk or Mawk (won't work with BSD/OSX Awk).

Comment: @mklement0 - Revised. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you have a single line `HTML` file that contains a script that contains a variable that contains the data you are looking for.

Your field delimiters are **either** `"p":"pm100", "v":[` **or** a comma and some digits.

For `pm25` this works, because it is the first, and there are no occurrences of `,21` or something similar before it.

However, for `pm10`, there are some that are associated with `pm25` ahead of it. So the *second* field contains the empty string between `,21` and `,112`

@karakfa has a hack that seems to work -- but he doesn't explain very well why it works.

What he does is use `awk`'s record separator (which is usually a newline) and sets it to either of `:`, `,`, or `[`. So in your case, one of the records would be `"pm25"`, because it is preceded by a colon, which is a separator, and succeeded by a comma, also a separator.

Once it hits the matching content (`"pm25"`) it sets a counter to 4. Then, for this and the next records, it counts this counter down. `"pm25"` itself, `"v"`, the empty string between `:` and `[`, and finally reaches one when hitting the record with the number you want to output: `4 && ! 3` is false, `3 && ! 2` is false, `2 && ! 1` is false, but `1 && ! 0` is true. Since there is no execution block, `awk` simply prints this record, which is the value you want.

A more robust work would probably be using `xpath` to find the script, then use some `json` parser or similar to get the value.

Comment: Nice explanation, except for the statement "It will continue to count c into the negatives".  Please correct.

Comment: You're right, I didn't know how `--c` works. I tried it out and `c` doesn't count below 0. I took the line out.

Comment: Once `c` hits 0, the short-circuit logic of `&&` prevents the RHS of `c&&!--c` from being evaluated.  Neat, concise, and clever, yes, but also a bit sneaky.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

If you have to, you can use this hacky way using smart counters with hand-crafted delimiters. Setting RS instead of FS transfers looping through fields to awk itself. Multi-char RS is not available for all awks (gawk supports it).

```
$ awk -v RS='[:,[]' '$0=="\"pm25\""{c=4} c&&!--c' file                 
59

$ awk -v RS='[:,[]' '$0=="\"pm10\""{c=4} c&&!--c' file   
15
```